# Send Push notification on specific event occur in website using ionic and google cloud

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I want to send push notification to specific user on specific event occur on website like new post add on website or new products are on website.

So, how to send push notification in ionic using google cloud. And i want this functionality for android.

Comment: Is there no one who can help me out?

Comment: If you want to `send push notification in ionic`, you can take look at [here](https://thinkster.io/ionic-push-notifications-tutorial/).

Comment: But I want to use GCM not parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git

Allows your application to receive push notifications. To receive notifications in your controllers or services, listen for $cordovaPush:notificationReceived event.

go through 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

Additional Resources:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial
http://tokudu.com/post/50024574938/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android